# Designing Docker Environment with Test Files on Host Machine Python

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing, dockerfile, pytest

I am working on a project within a Docker environment, and I want to separate my PyTest test files from the Docker image. Specifically, I would like to have the test files stored in a separate directory (`tests/`) on the host machine. Is there a way to run the PyTest tests for the Python files within the Docker container while keeping the test files on the host machine?

Details:

```
Host Machine:
├── project/
│ ├── code/
│ │ ├── file1.py
│ │ ├── file2.py
│ │ └── ...
│ └── tests/
│ ├── test_file1.py
│ ├── test_file2.py
│ └── ...
└── Dockerfile

Docker Machine:
└── code/
├── file1.py
├── file2.py
└── ...
```

Objective:

1. I want to execute PyTest tests for the Python files within the Docker container.
2. The test files are located in the tests/ directory on the host machine.
3. I want to avoid including the test files directly in the Docker image.

Questions:

1. How can I configure my Docker setup to run PyTest tests for the Python files within the Docker container while keeping the test files on the host machine?
2. Are there any specific volume mappings or configurations needed to make the test files accessible within the Docker container?
3. What would be the recommended approach or best practices for achieving this separation between the test files on the host machine and the Docker environment?

Any insights or guidance on how to accomplish this setup and run PyTest tests within the Docker container while keeping the test files on the host machine would be greatly appreciated.